# If I have 2 UserControls on a MainWindow view, and I want to pass a property between them, how do I do it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have two UserControls, 1 contains just a TreeView and the other will be a form that loads when an item in the TreeView is selected.

Like this Options Dialog.

[image: Options Dialog]

I've already run into several issues with TreeView's SelectedItem property, but have found several solutions to get the SelectedItem in either the TreeView's codebehind file, or in its ViewModel.

**My Question is:**
How do I pass the SelectedItem of my TreeView from the UserControl it belongs to, to a ContentControl in the same window?

This is an example of what I mean:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MicroMVVM.View">
    <v:TreeViewControl /> <!-- Pass SelectedItem from here -->
    <ContentControl Content="TreeViewsSelectedItem" /> <!-- To here. -->
</Window>
```

Comment: Personally I would bind `ContentControl.Content` to `MyTreeView.SelectedItem`, and use `DataTemplates` to tell WPF how to draw the different item types. I have some examples of both changing the `DataTemplate` based on a property such as a string, or using implicit `DataTemplates` [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a property of the correct type to your whatever object is set as your `Window.DataContext` and then just bind to that value from both the child views:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MicroMVVM.View">
    <v:TreeViewControl SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
</Window>
```

You might even be able to bind directly:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MicroMVVM.View">
    <v:TreeViewControl Name="TreeViewControl" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeViewControl}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm attempting to use your suggestion, however it doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? They are two different Data Contexts and when I try to bind directly, I get an Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedNode' property not found on 'object'

Comment: Which one didn't work? For the first suggestion, try adding a `DependencyProperty` into the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file and bind to it from both properties as shown... you might need to add `Mode=TwoWay` to the `Binding`s. The second example really should work as it is.